# Can not modify the column in persist method - Hibernate Trigger

Tags: hibernate, triggers

I want to insert a record with Hibernate with the entityManager.persist (entity) method; but throws this error:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column can not be modified "TABLE_FIELD" because it is a calculated column or is the result of a UNION operator.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535)
```

Why does it show that "Can not modify the column" if I am trying to insert a record?

**Info**:
- I'm using jdk 1.7, Spring 4.3.10.RELEASE and Hibernate 4.3.11.Final
- When I run the INSERT directly in the BD SQL Server, I can insert a new record
- The field that indicates the error comes NULL, but should exit error when inserting NULL and not what the log shows
- Apparently there is a trigger in the database that hibernate can not handle

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column in your mappings which is solely driven by the database, you should indicate that in the mapping so that Hibernate does not include it in its DML statements.

```
@Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
@Column("some_calculated_field", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String someCalculatedField;
```

As you can see I've marked it as `insertable=false` and `updatable=false` so that field is effectively skipped when generating `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.  That should fix the trigger problem.

**Update**

I updated the mapping to include `@Generated` to solve your null value issue.

When using `GenerationTime.ALWAYS`, a `SELECT` statement will be invoked after both an `INSERT` and `UPDATE` to fetch the value of the calculated column from the database.  If the trigger fires only during an `INSERT`, you can improve `UPDATE` performance by changing the the annotation to `GenerationType.INSERT` so that the `SELECT` statement only fires on `INSERT`.

Comment: Thank!! I was with this problem all day. I had already tried putting "updatable = false" but I forgot to try the "insertable". Thank you very much!

Comment: There is a problem, when insert a new record by Hibernate the calculated field is Null and when insert directly by the database, the calculated field updates its value

Comment: @iv18 I updated the answer with `@Generated` to aid you with dealing with fetching the DB generated value.

Comment: I tried again and the calculated column showed NULL because one of the columns within the formula was NULL, so the calculated columns do not need the Generated annotation (only: insertable = false, updatable = false). On the other hand, I have other columns of the table that are modified after INSERT with constraints of the database (they were not triggers) and in these columns I do need the annotation Generated (value = GenerationTime.INSERT) so that the constraints run in the database. I was already resigned to replicate those constraints by the app. Again, thank you very much